# How can I take multiple digit positive integers as input in LC3?

Tags: assembly, lc3

I have a program that should take two natural numbers as input.
Below is my current attempt, which doesn't work. All the labels you don't see are of course elsewhere in the code, I don't believe them to be the problem. The goal is to get a number in R1 and a number in R2.

```
START           LD R6, ASCII        ; load ascii offset for printing numbers
                NOT R6, R6
                ADD R6, R6, #1

                AND R1, R1, #0
INPUT1          TRAP x20
                ADD R5, R0, R6
                BRn INPUT2          ; whatever was inputted wasn't a digit, value in R1 is the correct value
                ADD R3, R5, #-9     
                BRp INPUT2          ; whatever was inputted wasn't a digit, value in R1 is the correct value
                ; input was a digit. multiply R1 by 10 and add it
                AND R3, R3, #0
                ADD R3, R3, #9
                ADD R4, R1, #0      
MULT1           ADD R1, R4, R1
                ADD R3, R3, #-1
                BRp MULT1           ; we are multiplying by 10
                ADD R1, R1, R5      ; add the input
                BRnzp INPUT1
                
                AND R2, R2, #0
INPUT2          TRAP x20
                ADD R5, R0, R6
                BRn PREP          ; whatever was inputted wasn't a digit, value in R2 is the correct value
                ADD R3, R5, #-9     
                BRp PREP          ; whatever was inputted wasn't a digit, value in R2 is the correct value
                ; input was a digit. multiply R2 by 10 and add it
                AND R3, R3, #0
                ADD R3, R3, #9
                ADD R4, R2, #0
MULT2           ADD R2, R4, R2
                ADD R3, R3, #-1
                BRp MULT2           ; we are multiplying by 10
                ADD R2, R2, R5      ; add the input
                BRnzp INPUT2
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: You have the right idea, mathematically speaking (multiply by 10 and add next), so what's your question?  Code-wise, I'd use a subroutine to get a a number from the user, so you can do it twice.  I'd also use a loop to handle multiple digits rather than copy & paste & paste the same input & multiplication code.

Comment: You're right, I definitely should use a subroutine. That being said, the code I pasted doesn't work, and I can't seem to figure out why not. So my questions is, where does it go wrong? I have edited the post with this info.

Comment: Have you used the debugger to look at register values while you single-step it?  You should know from the algorithm what the expected results are at some key points.  It's much easier to check that with a debugger than by *carefully* simulating it in our heads.

Comment: Ok, so this is a great time to upgrade your debugging skills.  Single step and observe the effect of each instruction.  Compare with your mental model of what it should do, and try to identify the first instruction that goes wrong from what you're expecting.

Comment: Also, really helpful is to have a version of same in a language you know well. To input a 2 digit number should be about 7-8 lines of code in a high level language, if you also do the multiplication using loops. If you do that, you'll make sure your algorithms are correct and all you have left to do is to faithfully reproduce the algorithm in assembly. During assembly debugging, you will have an actual working other version to compare with at each step.